# My custom find-and-replace code not working properly

Tags: java, replace

I've create two custom find-and-replace methods, but they're not working properly.

This is my find-and-replace code:

```
public final class StringTools {
    public static String replaceAll(String text, String replace, String replacement) {
        if (replace == replacement)
            return text;

        String currentText = null;
        String newText = text;
        do {
            currentText = newText;
            newText = replaceFirst(newText, replace, replacement);
        } while (currentText != newText);
        return newText;
    }

    public static String replaceFirst(String text, String replace, String replacement) {
        int found = 0;
        int foundAt = -1;

        // Loop through each char
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            char c = text.charAt(i);
            // Does char match replace char?
            if (replace.charAt(found) == c) {
                // We found another match
                found++;

                // Have we found the entire replace text?
                if (found == replace.length()) {
                    // Mark location we found match first at
                    foundAt = i - found + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }


        // Did we get a match?
        if (foundAt != -1) {
            // Replace text
            return text.substring(0, foundAt) + replacement    + text.substring(foundAt + replace.length(), text.length());
        }
        return text;
    }
}
```

Most of my attempts to try this code gave successful results. However, I found a case where my code fails, but I'm not sure why...

Here's that code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "{r}0{0}/{r} 10 players";

    text = StringTools.replaceAll(text, "{0}", "[test]");

    System.out.println(text);
}
```

However, this outputs:

*{r}0[test]/[test] 10 players*

As you can see, it replaces the first '{0}' like expected, but for some reason it also replaces the '{r}'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Cheers! :)

Comment: What's the point? Can you use regex? Assume you can't use any string replace method.

Comment: It seems you're using `!=` and `==` to compare strings. That does not work in Java, and you must use `someString.equals(anotherString)`.

Comment: It has to do with how you are counting the characters in replaceFirst. On the second pass after the first {0} is replaced you will match on the first { then match on the 0 then finally match on the very last } and the foundAt will be pointing at that last character in the {r}. You need to make sure your replaceFirst method is only checking consecutive characters.

Comment: @twreid That explains it! I feel a bit silly now... Anywho, thank you, I made it work now :)